# Haskell synonym definition

Tags: haskell

Could someone explain me what the following synonim means and how to read it:

```
type TCM a = ErrorT String (StateT MyEnv IO) a
```

What I was able to understand up till now:

- we say that we introduce new name for some type and now we say that we call it TCM and it has some parameter a
- We have value constructor ErrorT (what makes ErrorT?) that takes three arguments: String,  (StateT MyEnv IO) and a
- (StateT MyEnv IO) - we say here that we have value constructor StateT and args MyEnv and IO. But what this type makes?

Am I right? Could anyone explain me how it works? Thanks for any responses.

Edit: Maybe someone could help me also with this. I have sth the following function in my program that evaluate Integer:

```
ms_exp :: Exp -> TCM ()    
ms_exp (EInt integer) = do
    return integer
```

and it have such error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `()' with actual type `Integer'
```

Any hints?

Comment: ErrorT and StateT are not value constructors, but type constructors. The right hand side of a type definition is just a type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Well, the `ErrorT` type already had the `a` type parameter, if we wished, we could specialize it, that is, make type

   ```
   type TCMInt = ErrorT String (StateT MyEnv IO) Int
   ```

   However, we can leave it as a type parameter, as you did in your example.
2. No, `ErrorT` is not a *value* constructor, it is a *type* constructor. What makes an element of `ErrorT`? Well, that depends on what `ErrorT` is. I suppose it is [Control.Monad.Error](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/1.1.0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Error.html), and it is said that is is constructed by the `runErrorT` function.
3. Again, `StateT` is not a *value* constructor, it is a *type* constructor (created with `newtype` keyword acoording to [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/1.1.0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html)). As you can see from `newtype State s a`, the `State` type constructors expects two type names to construct a type, so your code passes `MyEnv` and `IO`, yielding the `StateT MyEnv IO` type.

To the update: your function expects to inject an element of `()` into the `TCM` monad by doing `return ()` while you do `return integer`. You need either `return ()` or change the type of `ms_exp` to `Exp -> TCM Integer`.